# display json data in recyclerview with cardview

Tags: json, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am trying to display the data on my json file on a listview with recyclerview and cardview. 
When I launch my app, it just displays a blank screen. I am not sure what I did wrong since there is no error on android studio.

Can one please double check my code and help me fix my mistakes. I tried searching the forum and youtube for a solution with no luck.

Below are my json file and mainactivity.java.

My json file

```
{
"movie": [
{
"title": "movie1",
"genre": "action",
"imgURL": "https://demonuts.com/Demonuts/SampleImages/roger.jpg"
},
{
"title": "movie2",
"genre": "romance",
"imgURL": "https://demonuts.com/Demonuts/SampleImages/murray.jpg"
},
{
"title": "movie3",
"genre": "drama",
"imgURL": "https://demonuts.com/Demonuts/SampleImages/djoko.jpg"
},
{
"title": "movie4",
"genre": "comedie",
"imgURL": "https://demonuts.com/Demonuts/SampleImages/nadal.jpg"
}
]
}
```

mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ExampleAdapter mExampleAdapter;
private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();

    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    parseJSON();
}

private void parseJSON() {
    String url = "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5c2fc20381fe89272a845c69/1";

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("movie");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject movie = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String title = movie.getString("title");
                            String imageUrl = movie.getString("imageURL");
                            String genre = movie.getString("genre");

                            mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(imageUrl, title, genre));
                        }

                        mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mExampleList);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change movie.getString("imageURL"); to movie.getString("imgURL")

```
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject movie = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String title = movie.getString("title");
                            String imageUrl = movie.getString("imgURL");
                            String genre = movie.getString("genre");

                            mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(imageUrl, title, genre));
                        }
```

Comment: Your json string value is imgURL but you are fetching it as movie.getString("imageURL");

Comment: If you still didn't get it replace the code in my answer instead of your for loop part.

Comment: then there might be other issues too. Do you have any errors in log?